# some images not appearing on the website after migration

Tags: images

we just migrated our website to a new server. few images on our website is not showing up but in edit mode, the images are seen.[image]

Comment: Actually, resaving permalinks helped for me in similar situations. Also there are specific plugin that solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your migration wasn't done successfully. 
The images in the slider point nothing. Which means the value of img's src property is empty.

You'd better check the procedure of your migration again.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response.
Does this mean, we re-do the migration or is there any alternate fix?

Comment: For some reasons, the image src value wasn't migrated. That's why I mentioned you'd better check what you did to migrate the site.

Comment: The migration was done by a remote service provider, and I'm checking with them. However, would you recommend what could be the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: If I were you, I would contact the remote service provider.

Comment: I have already raised the issue with the remote service provider and waiting for their response. But while they respond i was just trying to check what could be a fix to this issue.

Comment: You can compare old and new database tables. If you are pretty sure that the slider image is only issue, you can add images manually on slider plugin setting page if you use slider plugin.

Comment: The strange part is when I login as an Admin and try to edit the content, I can see all the images but when I preview, they disappear.

Comment: If you are using cache plugin, turn off during testing. Then upload images and set the images on slider plugin's setting page again. Then it will update db. That's only what I can guess to solve without information what service provider did.

Comment: No, not using cache plugin

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all. the issue got resolved. We found out that there was server folder permission which was not set correctly. ISSUE RESOLVED